# Complete a matrix using eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I want to complete a matrix using eigenvectors
For example the matrix
$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a  \\
    1 & b  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
have the eigenvectors $u=(1,1)$ and $v=(-2,1)$

The answer matrix is 
$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2  \\
    1 & 2  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
But how I can show $a=2$ and $b=2 $?

I tried using Diagonalization $SMS^{-1}$ with arbitrary scalars and Characteristic Polynomial of A but I can't find $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go straight from the definition of eigenvector.  We know

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&a\\1&b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \alpha \begin{bmatrix}  1\\1 \end{bmatrix} $$ and

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&a\\1&b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -2\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \beta \begin{bmatrix}  -2\\1 \end{bmatrix} $$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  When we multiply out we get $$\begin{bmatrix} 1+a\\1+b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  \alpha  \\  \alpha  \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix} -2+a\\-2+b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  -2 \beta  \\  \beta  \end{bmatrix}.$$

These tell us $$1+a=1+b$$ and $$-2+a=4-2b.$$  The first gives us that $a=b$.  The latter then becomes $-2+a=4-2a$  or $3a=6$, so both $a$ and $b$ are $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use eigen vectors/values definition. Solve this linear system of 4 equations for ($a,b,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$)

$
A \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]\lambda_1
$

$
A \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -2 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]= 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -2 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \lambda_2
$

Where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues for each eigenvector